# How https request is handling using NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, https, nsurlconnectiondelegate

Can anybody help me to know how https request are processing using NSRULConnection? I had gone through lot of tutorials and Apple documentation. But I am not able to understand how it is working. I have implemented the following delegates to process an https request.

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace 
{    
    return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{       
    [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

When I implemented the above delegate, I got response from the server successfully. Can anyone help me to know how this is working. Also what are each parameters in the delegate and what it is doing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the `protectionSpace` as the server. The delegate method `connection: canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace` is used to ask you if you **can** handle the authentication requirements of the server. In your case, you say "if we're talking about the SSL certificate (that's what `NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust` usually means), yes, I can handle that".

The connection then asks you to **do** just that with `connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` and provide a NSURLCredential for this specific server. With `credentialForTrust:` you create the credential by using the information stored in your keychain for the certificate of this server. With `useCredential:forAuthenticationChallenge:` you finally tell the connection to answer the challenge with this credential, i.e. use the keychain data to validate the certificate.

Comment: Thanks Dorian for your explanantion. Can you give a little more explanation about the term NSURLAuthenticationChallenge?

Comment: Also I have a few more queries, do we need to add certificates on keychain for https connection? My assumption is that I have to use SSL certificate. If we want to use custom user credential, do we need to implement only the above mentioned delegates or just connection:willsendrequestforauthenticationchallenge?

Comment: If you can make successful https-requests with the above delegate methods in place, you don't need to add your certificate, because ios seems to know its root CA. If the server asks for user credentials, that's a different kind of auth challenge (e.g. NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic). You'd have to check for that type and then provide a different credential, e.g. using [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:password:persistence:]

Answer (score 0):

This example will help you [How To Use iOS NSURLConnection By Example](http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/)